# How to use _dirname with a sibling directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, directory, router

My directory is set up like this:

```
public 
    pages
       index.html
routers
    route.js
```

Inside route.js, I do the following:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("/public/pages/index.html", {"root": __dirname});
});
```

I get **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat** because the server is looking on `myproject/routers/public/pages/index.html` and not `myproject/public/pages/index.html`

1) How do I fix this issue and get it to look in the right path using `_dirname`?

2) How do I get my server to remember looking in `/public/pages/` so that I don' have to specify the absolute path every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you probably want to use relative location, for your example you can do something like bellow

```
var html_location = './public/pages/'; //first method
var root_location = {  //second method
    root : './public/pages/'
}
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root : html_location}); //first method
    res.sendFile('index.html', root_location); //second method
});
```

so the root : '.' indicating that you will be starting the location from the folder where the main.js / app.js file is running and the file location is off from that location.

Comment: Is there a way to make it neater so that I do not have to hardcode `./public/pages/` everytime?

Comment: yes you can do `res.sendFile('index.html', { root : './public/pages/'});`

Comment: i see what you are asking, you can put a variable at the top of the page `var html_location = './public/page/'` and use that inside the root, or even set the root object at the top of the page